# imagecreatefrompng() generating black background instead of transparent part in image

Tags: php

I make an image using PHP but my code turn png transparency into a solid black color, Is there a solution to improve my code?

```
$filename = 'https://i.ibb.co/9sB9rTM/small-408587143-15774386991of1-2-2-Original-0-test.png';
$widthsrc=0;
$heightsrc=0;


$src1 = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
list($widthsrc, $heightsrc, $typesrc, $attrsrc) = getimagesize($filename);

$background = imagecolorallocatealpha($src1, 255, 255, 255, 127);
$pre = imagecolortransparent($src1, $background);

imagealphablending($src1, false);
imagesavealpha($src1, true);
imagepng($src1);
```

Comment: Your code produces an image that looks almost the same as the source image ( after adding the Content-Type header anyway ) ~ please clarify your question as I don't really see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

First use always header like:

> header("Content-type: image/png");

Second are you sure when you save image 'black solid' is not trasparent?

Example of creating image:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = 'TEXT';
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/button1.png");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Comment: Hey Simone Rossaini,

I want to generate same output image as source image with transparent background.

Check my below link source image.
https://i.ibb.co/9sB9rTM/small-408587143-15774386991of1-2-2-Original-0-test.png

And check my output image. it having black background instead of transparent background.
https://i.ibb.co/PhCcnZ6/0-1-box-small-408587143-15774386991of1-2-2-Original-0-test.jpg

Comment: The first image is PNG, so have a transparent bg, the second image is JPG so can't have a transparent bg